# iOS Flutter app opens, but is stuck on splash-screen

Tags: ios, flutter, splash-screen

When I built my iOS app, it opened perfectly in the simulator on my Macbook.
When I publish the app on the itunes store, the app does not work anymore. The splashscreen is shown, but stays on the screen.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Solution for me:

1. updated my iOS toolchain with flutter doctor
2. `flutter clean`
3. `flutter build ios --release` in the terminal
4. Archive in Xcode

Comment: I face this problem sometimes in Android. It's weird because it doesn't happen all the times, just a few times.

Answer (score 3):

I fix this by remove `project_root/ios/Pods/` & `project_root/ios/Podfile.lock` and run `pod install` again after `flutter clean` & `flutter build ios --release`

Answer (score 1):

I tried various solutions. But finally i found out issue was version of my android studio(ide used for development for flutter, in my case). I updated my version to 3.2.1 and then followed instructions to run in xcode and it worked in my case.
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I added `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()`to the main page.

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with an android build of an app that uses multiple flavors, but in the end it turned out I was simply using the wrong APK file.

So the build created 3 apk files eg.

```
myapp.apk
myapp-test-debug.apk
myapp-test-release.apk
```

My assumption was to use the `test-release.apk` which got the app stuck on the splash screen. Using the `myapp.apk` did not have this problem.

Bit of a facepalm moment for myself but maybe this helps someone else looking for an answer!

Answer (score 0):

I face the same issues, and I finally found that the root of the problem is the setting of workspace of xcode,when i change the workspace settings from legacy build system to new build system,the bug disappear . hope can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Podfile is out of date.

Solution for me:

1. Remove Pobfile folder and Pobfile.lock direction: "your_flutter_project/ios/"
2. Run `flutter clean`
3. Run `flutter pub get`
4. Run `flutter build ios`

Hope this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If non of the above solutions work for you on ios, Try this. In xcode under Targets > General. Set Main interface to Main and set luanch screen file to LaunchScreen.

This worked for me on IOS.