# Release build loads only the splash screen of the app in IOS Xcode Flutter

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

When in debug mode app works fine. But during the release build it loads only the splash screen. But when I tick debug executable in release mode.The app is working fine. Please guide. Sorry for the format.
Apple rejects my app

> Guideline 2.1 - Performance - App Completeness
>
> We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPad
>   running iOS 12.4 on Wi-Fi.
>
> Specifically, your app only launched to a splash screen with no other
>   content available to the user.
>
> Next Steps
>
> To resolve this issue, please run your app on a device to identify any
>   issues, then revise and resubmit your app for review.

Answer (score 1):

You should be write following command in terminal(Android Studio/Visual Code)

```
rm -rf $HOME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*

# destroy entire flutter cache (will be redownloaded and rebuilt)
# rm -rf $HOME/Library/Flutter/bin/cache/*

# sometimes Flutter doesn't recompile the frameworks
rm -rf ios/Flutter/App.framework ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework

# remove the entire pub-cache
rm -rf ~/.pub-cache/*

# now, remove the build directory
rm -rf build

# now remove the .packages file
rm -f .packages

# now remove the plugins directory
rm -rf .flutter-plugins

pushd ios
pod deintegrate
rm -rf Pods Podfile.lock
rm -rf .symlinks/*
popd

flutter packages get
```

Answer (score 0):

Do clean of code by `flutter clean`

Install pods for iOS by
`cd ios` then `pod install`.

Then make release build for iOS by `flutter build ios --release`.

Now you can open iOS project in xcode and only splash screen issue will be fixed.

Answer (score -1):

Same thing happened to me:

```
flutter clean
flutter build ios --release
```

Was all I needed (didn't need to do the `pod install`).

A few links that might also be helpful:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22765#issuecomment-449618558

[Flutter app opens, but is stuck on splash-screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54133443/flutter-app-opens-but-is-stuck-on-splash-screen)

Answer (score -1):

You need to build initially from Android studio for iOS.

Initially clean your project - `flutter clean`

Then run below line in terminal of Android studio.

```
flutter build ios --release
```

Now, open XCode and clean project then make your archive. Your issue of stuck in Splash is resolved.