# How to solve Flutter iOS app stuck at splash screen in release mode?

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, mobile, apple-m1

I got a problem when i tried to open my flutter app for first time after installing in release mode (I'm using diawi and TestFlight). It stuck at splash screen, sometimes app can enter to MyApp page after terminate app. It's running well when I run from debug mode (ctrl + F5) or debug in Xcode.

flutter doctor result:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.11, on macOS 13.4 22F66 darwin-arm64, locale
    en-ID)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version
    32.1.0-rc1)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.78.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

• No issues found!
```

Steps I already do:

1. `flutter clean`
2. `flutter build ios`
3. `pod install`

but still no luck after trying these step.

anyone got clue how to solve this?

Steps I already do:

1. `flutter clean`
2. `flutter build ios`
3. `pod install`

I followed steps from this [Flutter app opens, but is stuck on splash-screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54133443/flutter-app-opens-but-is-stuck-on-splash-screen). I did some delete podfile too. but it still got stuck in splash screen.

Comment: Hello, did you find the solution for this?

Comment: hello, it caused by my APNS token. I added some script and key to info.plist. you can follow the instructions here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58246620/apns-device-token-not-set-before-retrieving-fcm-token-for-sender-id-react-nati